# What is the difference between Observer and LifecycleObserver?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-architecture-lifecycle

I am struggling to understand the difference between `LiveData` being a `LifecycleObserver` and the `Observer` that the `LiveData` object receives in the `observe()` method.

Am I right saying that the `LiveData` is a `LifecycleObserver` and so it knows about the `Activity` because of it?

And that the `Observer` received in the `observe()` method has nothing to do with `LifecycleObserver` because it is there just to execute the `onChange()` method when there is a change in `LiveData`?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right saying that the `LiveData` is a `LifecycleObserver` and so it knows about the `Activity` because of it?

Yes.

> And that the `Observer` received in the `observe()` method has nothing to do with `LifecycleObserver` because it is there just to execute the `onChange()` method when there is a change in `LiveData`?

Yes.

---

As the name suggests, a `LifecycleObserver` is supposed to keep track of changes happening to the lifecycle of its parent (`Activity` or `Fragment` or any other `LifecycleOwner`), making `LiveData` lifecycle-aware.

The `Observer` on the other hand keeps track of changes happening to the `value` of this `LiveData` object.

So you are correct. `Observer` has nothing to do with `LifecycleObserver`.